# Problem getting all child elements and adding to their ClassList using querSelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I have two divs, each containing a bunch of  elements with the class tm-tag. I want to differentiate what div these elements are from by their class so I can get for other functions.

My HTML is basically:

```
<div id="expensetags>
   <span class="tm-tag"></span>
   <span class="tm-tag"></span>
   <span class="tm-tag"></span>
</div>

<div id="incometags>
   <span class="tm-tag"></span>
   <span class="tm-tag"></span>
   <span class="tm-tag"></span>
</div>
```

When the function is called I want all span items in the first div to have "expense" added to their class list and all items in the second div to have "income" added.

**Here is the code, I thought would do the trick:**

```
function tagcategories(){
  let expensesdiv = document.getElementById("expensetags")
  let expenses = expensesdiv.querySelectorAll('.tm-tag')
  let incomesdiv = document.getElementById("incometags")
  let incomes = incomesdiv.querySelectorAll('.tm-tag')
   expenses.classList.add("expense");
   incomes.classList.add("income");
}
```

Sadly I always get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined".

Any idea where my mistake is? Am I using querySelectorAll the correct way?

Comment: you have to iterate the nodelist - theres no `classList` property like how jquery does it.

Comment: BTW you can use `querySelectorAll("#expensetags .tm-tag")` in one shot.

Comment: You're missing quotes, but you need to loop over your `querySelectorAll` resulting nodeList to use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), which does exist on single Elements.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using forEach to iterate the node list:

```
expenses.forEach(function(el){
  el.classList.add("expense"); })
  incomes.forEach(function(el){
    el.classList.add("income"); })
}
```